# php cURL Operation timed out after 120308 milliseconds with X out of -1 bytes received

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I'm experiencing this error (see Title) occasionally in my scraping script.

X is the integer number of bytes > 0, the real number of bytes the webserver sent in response. I debugged this issue with Charles proxy and here is what I see

[image: Charles debug session with problematic request]

As you can see there is no Content-Length: header in response, and the proxy still waits for the data (and so the cURL waited for 2 minutes and gave up)

The cURL error code is 28.

Below is some debug info from verbose curl output with var_export'ed curl_getinfo() of that request:

```
* About to connect() to proxy 127.0.0.1 port 8888 (#584)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x2f14d58
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 584 (0x2f14d58) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#584)
> GET http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/sof/3834062623.html HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Firefox (WindowsXP) Ц Mozilla/5.1 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB
; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6
Host: bakersfield.craigslist.org
Accept: */*
Referer: http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/sof/3834062623.html
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
< Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 21:50:17 GMT
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 21:50:17 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< X-MCP-Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 21:55:17 GMT
* HTTP/1.1 proxy connection set close!
< Proxy-Connection: Close
<
* Operation timed out after 120308 milliseconds with 4636 out of -1 bytes receiv
ed
* Closing connection 584
Curl error: 28 Operation timed out after 120308 milliseconds with 4636 out of -1
 bytes received http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/sof/3834062623.htmlarray (
  'url' => 'http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/sof/3834062623.html',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
  'http_code' => 200,
  'header_size' => 362,
  'request_size' => 337,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 120.308,
  'namelookup_time' => 0,
  'connect_time' => 0,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 4636,
  'speed_download' => 38,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => 0,
  'starttransfer_time' => 2.293,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'certinfo' =>
  array (
  ),
  'primary_ip' => '127.0.0.1',
  'primary_port' => 8888,
  'local_ip' => '127.0.0.1',
  'local_port' => 63024,
  'redirect_url' => '',
)
```

Can I do something like adding a curl option to avoid these timeouts. And this is not a connection timeout, nor data wait timeout - both of these settings do not work as curl actually connects successfully and receives some data, so the timeout in error is always ~= 120000 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you're trying to parse Craigslist; could it be an anti-flood protection of theirs? 
Does the problem still exist if you try to parse other website? I once had the same issue trying to recursively map an FTP.

Regarding the timeouts, if you are sure that is isn't neither a connection timeout nor a data wait timeout (CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT / CURLOPT_TIMEOUT) I'd try increasing the limit of the PHP script itself:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but set_time_limit was there, the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT options are changed by the array of options passed to curl wrapper class instance and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option was  there when I ran the previous tests and I just added CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option to that array , verified it was set to the curl handle and re-run , but again , in 10-20 requests the same problem is there.

Comment: I still think its some kind of anti-flood mechanism of theirs. Try making like 1 request per second or less, see if it still happens.

Comment: Did you try to connect using an other way like telnet to connect to it? Maybe you will have some more information.

Comment: By the way, Craisglist terms of use explicitly prohibits crawlers.

Comment: Thanks Hal, it's not my project/idea. I'm going to award this to you as this is the only answer. Will try to add sleep call, but now it also works more or less with this glitch, so it just takes 2 minutes on these failures, then it continues as usual, and there are not so many of them if it runs 24/7

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I couldn't help out more.

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing `default_socket_timeout` in your PHP config file `php.ini` (e.g. `~/php.ini`), e.g.

```
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

or set it via [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP code as:

```
curl_setopt($res, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
```

where `$res` is your existing resource variable.